# Firefox can't show pictures?

Tags: html, image, firefox

I made a website. In this website I want to show pictures dynamically.

It works very well in Chrome. However, I can't see the pictures in FireFox.

My code as follows:

the value of directory is `pictures\Tom\2014-08-14-01-52-01\beautiful.jpg`

```
function addpictures(array){
    var frame = document.getElementById("show_pictures");

    for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        var index = array[i].PICTURE.indexOf("pictures");
        directory=array[i].PICTURE.substring(index,array[i].PICTURE.length);
        var node = document.createElement("div");
        // the value of directory is "pictures\Tom\2014-08-14-01-52-01\beautiful.jpg"
        node.innerHTML = '<img src='+directory+'   width="800" height="600" alt="\"/><br/><br/>';
        frame.insertBefore(node);
    }
}


<div id="show_pictures" align="center">
<p id="description"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Look in the console and network tab.

Comment: http://xkcd.com/727/

Comment: HTTP protocol or File protocol?

Answer (score 2):

URLs use forward slashes, not backslashes.

Chrome is kind enough to fix that for you, which is why you didn't notice this earlier.

Comment: Shouldn't the URL start with a forward slash also?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
./pictures/Tom/2014-08-14-01-52-01/beautiful.jpg
```

Comment: As `./path/to/image.jpg` is in this situation the same as `path/to/image.jpg` you should explain why adding `./` should solve the problem.